# Prisma findFirstOrThrow does not throw

Tags: prisma, vitest

Using prisma I am trying to write some tests, however the `findFirstOrThrow` method (https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#findfirstorthrow) does not seem to throw when nothing should be found. Instead it is returning the first database record it finds.

The following piece of code is what I am testing

```
console.log('sessionId', this.ctx.session?.user?.id);

const author = await this.db.author.findFirstOrThrow({
  where: { userId: this.ctx.session?.user?.id },
  select: { id: true },
});

console.log({ author });
```

And in my test output I get the following logs

```
RERUN  src/api/service.ts x31

stdout | src/api/service.test.ts > BlockService > block creation > without an author
sessionId undefined

stdout | src/api/service.test.ts > BlockService > block creation > without an author
{ author: { id: 'cle79pisg007hb2b8rhpii1ws' } }
```

So even though the `this.ctx.session?.user?.id` is `undefined`, prisma still returns the first *author* in the table.

What I've tried so far:

- When not populating the authors table in the test it will throw.
- When populating the authors table with a single author it will return this author
- When giving an explicit `undefined` as the `userId` it will still returns the first record

edit: I use prisma ^4.8.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour.

If you will pass `undefined` then it is equivalent to not passing any userId.
So, the query is equivalent to the following:

```js
const author = await this.db.author.findFirstOrThrow({
  where: { },
  select: { id: true },
});
```

And this query would return the first record from database.
For reference, here is the [section](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/null-and-undefined) that defines this behaviour.

Comment: thanks! I misread the docs and completely missed the nullable part. In my app, I can be 100% sure to have an userId so I can fix that in the test setup. Does the `findFirstOrThrow` throw the request when I pass in a valid `userId` that does not exist in the `author` table?

Comment: Yes, in that case you should get an error.